# problem with pandas DataFrame , not able understand the data

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am receiving data as bellow format.

I am unable to  use pandas DataFrame effectly.
Is there any possibility to make it happen.

data
['{"time":"12-JUN-2023", "into":"180.40", "inth":"184.05", "intl":"178.55", "intc":"181.55", "ssboe":"1686528000", "intv":"200890.00"}', '{"time":"09-JUN-2023", "into":"178.70", "inth":"182.25", "intl":"178.30", "intc":"179.45", "ssboe":"1686268800", "intv":"183344.00"}', '{"time":"08-JUN-2023", "into":"182.30", "inth":"187.45", "intl":"177.05", "intc":"177.90", "ssboe":"1686182400", "intv":"458453.00"}', '{"time":"07-JUN-2023", "into":"186.90", "inth":"188.25", "intl":"181.05", "intc":"181.50", "ssboe":"1686096000", "intv":"262740.00"}', '{"time":"06-JUN-2023", "into":"187.95", "inth":"189.45", "intl":"184.50", "intc":"185.90", "ssboe":"1686009600", "intv":"275835.00"}']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["time", "into", "inth", "intl", "intc", "ssboe", "intv"]);

the error I am getting
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (5, 1), indices imply (5, 7)

but the following code is working

### data1 = [{"time":"12-JUN-2023", "into":"180.40", "inth":"184.05", "intl":"178.55", "intc":"181.55", "ssboe":"1686528000", "intv":"200890.00"},{"time":"09-JUN-2023", "into":"178.70", "inth":"182.25", "intl":"178.30", "intc":"179.45", "ssboe":"1686268800", "intv":"183344.00"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=["time", "into", "inth", "intl", "intc", "ssboe", "intv"])
print(df['time'].values)

['12-JUN-2023' '09-JUN-2023']

I have tried this on my computer with latest python version.

Comment: Have you tried `pd.read_json` ? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transform the first data into an array of json like this:

`import json`

`data_transformed = [json.loads(d) for d in data]`

And then create the DataFrame:

`df = pd.DataFrame(data_transformed,columns=["time", "into", "inth", "intl", "intc", "ssboe", "intv"])`